# I have a problem with getting a geolocation on flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I' am trying to get geolocation and then push it on other route, but it returns me smth like:

`W/ActivityThread(27303): SCHED: razewp.covid19_20/.MainActivity [81, r=36ms, a=8ms, w=31795ms]`

here's code: 
its my first file `loc_get.dart`

```
import 'package:geolocator/geolocator.dart';

class LocationGetter {
  var test;

  LocationGetter({
    this.test,
  });

  Future<void> getLoc() async {
    final position = await Geolocator().getCurrentPosition(desiredAccuracy: LocationAccuracy.high);
  }
}
```

this is my `loc.dart`:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:covid19_20/pages/loc_get.dart';

class Location extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _LocationState createState() => _LocationState();
}

class _LocationState extends State<Location> {

  void setupLoc() async {
    LocationGetter location = LocationGetter(
      test: '',
    );

    await location.getLoc();

    Navigator.pushReplacementNamed(context, '/loading', arguments: {
      'test': location.test,
    });
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    setupLoc();
  }

  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return SafeArea(
      child: Scaffold(
        body: Center(
          child: Text('Getting location...')
        ),
      )
    );
  }
}
```

How can I fix it? Is there any ways? I'm debugging on my MI 8 SE phone

Comment: you should probably break the problem into separate smaller parts: 1) get a location and print it to the console, 2) put that location into a variable, 3) launch a new route, 4) combine steps 1,2, and 3 by putting that variable into an argument of the route.

Comment: The position is only set on the internal variable position of your getLoc method. I guess you should change this to this.test = await GeoLocator.get...

Comment: i actually found out the problem, my phone uses higher than 28 sdk, thats why it doesnt work on it. Launching the avd using api 28 fixed the problem, thanks for answers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to change

```
  Future<void> getLoc() async {
final position = await Geolocator().getCurrentPosition(desiredAccuracy: LocationAccuracy.high);
```

}

to

```
      Future<void> getLoc() async {
final position = await Geolocator().getCurrentPosition(desiredAccuracy: LocationAccuracy.high);
this.test=position;
  }
```